# PHP: does gettext require LC_MESSAGES dirs?

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

To translate my PHP app I use compiled in gettext module. Here is a directory tree of translations made according to docs:

```
locale/
  cs_CZ/
    LC_MESSAGES/
       messages.po
       messages.mo
  de_DE/
    LC_MESSAGES/
       messages.po
       messages.mo
  fr_FR/
    LC_MESSAGES/
       messages.po
       messages.mo
```

**Question**: is it possible to get rid of LC_MESSAGES catalog? Will PHP be able to find translations if I use this structure?

```
locale/
  cs_CZ/
     messages.po
     messages.mo
  de_DE/
     messages.po
     messages.mo
  fr_FR/
     messages.po
     messages.mo
```

My PHP that switches translations:

```
<?php
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8');
    bindtextdomain("messages", "locale");
    bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", 'UTF-8');
    textdomain("messages");
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, no way around that. It's hardwired in the gettext library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only feasible workaround is creating a symlink `LC_MESSAGES -> .` in each language subdirectory. (But this complicates PHP application installation. FTP seldomly can create symlinks.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid `LC_MESSAGES` is a requirement.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it has something to do with the gettext cache.

Comment: Not really. `LC_MESSAGES` is a "localization category", a misnomer for things like text, currency, dates, numbers, etc. Check [this section on the gettext manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#index-locale-categories)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do that, you can use this composer package : [gettext/gettext](https://packagist.org/packages/gettext/gettext)

So you can have the folder organization as you desire or even something like that :

```
locales/
   cs_CZ.mo
   cs_CZ.po
   de_DE.mo
   de_DE.po
   fr_FR.mo
   fr_FR.po
```

Comment: And then, you're not really using `gettext`, but just it's syntax/file format. Not many benefits and all the slowness of pure-PHP code to handle hundreds, possibly thousands of strings with every request.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question in the title: **it does require**.

**Why?**
To my current understanding, `LC_MESSAGES` is one of the [many localization categories you could use with gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#index-locale-categories). You can change to another category using `dcgettext()`, for instance.

However, that's a bit confusing since gettext is supposed to be mainly used for text translation, and it might be weird to use it to localize dates, money, numbers or charsets.