# How can I use Gettext in PHP?

Tags: php, gettext

I did this so far

```
$locale = 'fr_FR';
$domain = 'bla';
$path = 'C:\wamp\www\site/lang';

putenv("LC_ALL={$locale}");
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain($domain, $path);
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
```

(bintextdomain returns `C:\wamp\www\site\lang`)

But I don't get my messages translated.

Using `echo dcgettext('bla', $english_message, 1);` and I get the original message shown, not the translation.

What is the "category" argument for? I just passed `1` because I don't know what is supposed to represent...

Comment: Look into the plain [`gettext`](http://php.net/gettext) function instead of [`dcgettext`](http://php.net/dcgettext). Then you don't have to relist domain and category redundantly. (They are for application and module grouping methinks.)

Comment: But that function doesn't accept the "domain" argument. I need domains because I have multiple components, they should have their own translations..

Comment: Would [`dgettext`](http://php.net/dgettext) fit the bill then?

Comment: Is there a way I can see what file was loaded, and the messages that were read by gettext?

Comment: doesn't work ,still get the english message

Comment: You have to restart your web server after putting a new language file in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$locale = 'fra';
```

`fr_FR` is for unix, more info on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: could this be the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192503/php-does-gettext-require-lc-messages-dirs  ?

Comment: tried that too it doesn't work:( also downloaded test files from here: http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2006/04/10/benchmarking-php-localization-is-gettext-fast-enough/ and all methods work except the php gettext extension version :s anyway, if I have to make my directory structure retarded like that, I don't want to use it anymore..