# localization using gettext :How to change mo file location?

Tags: php, mysql, gettext

I am using gettext php extension for translation.

I want to put all the mo files as below in a single folder
language/eng.mo
langauge/ch.mo
language/jp.mo

Current gettext configuration is as below
Dir path
locale/de_CH/LC_MESSAGES/en_US.mo

```
define('PROJECT_DIR', realpath('./'));
define('LOCALE_DIR', PROJECT_DIR .'/locale');
define('DEFAULT_LOCALE', 'en_US');
$encoding = 'UTF-8';
$locale = (isset($_SESSION['lang']))? $_SESSION['lang'] : DEFAULT_LOCALE;
// gettext setup
T_setlocale(LC_MESSAGES, $locale);
// Set the text domain as 'messages'
$our_domain = 'messages';
T_bindtextdomain($our_domain, LOCALE_DIR);
T_bind_textdomain_codeset($our_domain, $encoding);
T_textdomain($our_domain);
```

please help me to change location for mo files and set the local parameter.

Comment: No. Just no. The title is completely unintelligible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: does gettext require LC\_MESSAGES dirs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192503/php-does-gettext-require-lc-messages-dirs)

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Gettext requires the exact folder structure you mentioned, which is indeed quite verbose - but that's an ancient library as well, right? You can't ask much lol

See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105261/102960) for more details.